# Increment variable every page load with Flask?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a Flask website with the following code:

```
@app.route('/topic/<topic>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def questions(topic):
    g.db = connectDB()
    query = 'SELECT question FROM questions WHERE topic=\"' + topic + '\"'
    cur = g.db.execute(query)
    questions = [dict(question=row[0]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
    question = questions[i]['question']
    g.db.close()
    return render_template('topic.html', topic=topic, subject='chemistry', question=question)
```

I also have a form on that page which when submitted returns to the same page. However I want to be able to track how many times the form is submitted, a counter. So every time the page loads I want to add 1 to a variable. Is there some way to do this in Flask?

Thanks.

Comment: /topic/";drop%20table%20questions;

Comment: Sorry could you explain I don't understand?

Comment: You have a glaring sql injection in your code. Maybe you should read the tutorial at least: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/tutorial/views/

Comment: I read the tutorial, it states to use question marks when inserting, will it not make a difference for me because I'm only reading?

Comment: Looking past the SQL injection... does the counter need to persist between restarts, or is it OK if it's volatile?

Comment: Between restarts it should return to 0. Can someone please explain this SQL injection issue, if it is an issue I need to fix it, thanks :)

Comment: @user2426062 You seem to understand how SQL work. It's a whole programming language and SQL injection is when you let user write parts of that program. Please read some basic stuff, like http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp , and if that doesn't clarify it, google is your friend. P.S.: Again, you seem to understand what SQL is, so what seems to be the problem with the actual question? Just create a table for counters, add a row and then increment an integer value in your view: `update counters set cnt=cnt+1 where name='my_view_counter`".